# Fastest way to upload a large file to Google Cloud Storage in python?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have a large CSV file that is around 20GB large, I need to upload it to google cloud, it's one giant file, not split.  How do I upload this quickly?  Here is what I have:

```
def WriteFile2Cloud(filepath, filename):
    global config
    global debug
    if(debug):
        print("Writing to file: "+filename)
    session = GetSession()
    client = storage.Client(config.GoogleProjectID(), _http=session)
    bucket = client.get_bucket(config.GoogleBucketName())
    blob = bucket.blob(filename)
    file = blob.upload_from_file(filepath+"/"+filename)
```

Is there any way to speed up the file upload?

Comment: What is the upload speed of your Internet connection? What is the upload speed using your code? Google Cloud supports uploading objects in segments and in parallel and then combining. If this is a one-off process, I recommend using `gsutil -m filename gs://mybucket/filename`. Edit your question with details.

Comment: What about zipping the file up first?  Then unzip it when it finish uploading?

Comment: Well you can zip it up but keep in mind that there's time to zip it up and time to unzip it. 20GB isn't a large file compared to TBs. You're really limited by your upload speed since I/O is not a major factor.

Comment: You can zip the file before uploading, but you cannot unzip it in place once stored.

Comment: It's not useful to zip in that case then.

Comment: The fastest method of uploading to Cloud Storage is to use the `compose` API and composite objects:. https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/compose https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/composite-objects https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploads-downloads#parallel-composite-uploads